# Building a slick web app - what do I use for front end animations nowadays?

Tags: javascript, css, frontend, famo.us, velocity.js

I am having a hard time to figure out the right technology to build a modern web app with a slick front end.

Basically I am thinking of having a slide here, an automated scroll there and a animated bounce somewhere in my web application. Nothing too fancy. Maybe if it makes sense even more advanced animation, but nothing like a quick animation sequence with many particles.

I worked recently with http://famo.us/ and find it heavy loaded for most modern web app needs. I think http://julian.com/research/velocity/ is interesting too. What would you recommend to use, maybe something else?

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow since you're asking for resource recommendations rather than asking for help with a specific problem.

Comment: This question is not a good match for SO. You could start by reading some articles on http://jankfree.org/.

Comment: Even though I agree with the previous comments, this is a good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what technology you are going to use, if you are going to use HTML 5 + Javascript.. CSS3 Transforms and other GPU kicking animations are a good way to go.

Personally I like Transit a lot: http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

It has a dependency on jQuery, but handles a lot of the CSS animation events like 'done' etc, so you can build through chaining & queuing and cancel events when needed. This tends to be a pain in the ass when you have do it all with css-browser-prefixes.. Also it auto enables the GPU when possible.

```
$('.box')
  .transition({ x: -40 })
  .transition({ y: 40 })
  .transition({ x: 0 })
  .transition({ y: 0 });
```

But, if you want to go bad-ass, you can also use a little prefixer and handle the events manually without a library:

```
var pfx = ["webkit", "moz", "MS", "o", ""];
function PrefixedEvent(element, type, callback) {
    for (var p = 0; p < pfx.length; p++) {
        if (!pfx[p]) type = type.toLowerCase();
        element.addEventListener(pfx[p]+type, callback, false);
    }
}
```

In the css, you would then also have to manually write you animations. BUT a library like Transit saves you from all this boring css,

this would be how to write an css animation:

```
#anim.enable
{
    -webkit-animation: flash 1s ease 3;
    -moz-animation: flash 1s ease 3;
    -ms-animation: flash 1s ease 3;
    -o-animation: flash 1s ease 3;
    animation: flash 1s ease 3;
}

/* animation */
@-webkit-keyframes flash {
    50% { opacity: 0; }
}

@-moz-keyframes flash {
    50% { opacity: 0; }
}

@-ms-keyframes flash {
    50% { opacity: 0; }
}

@-o-keyframes flash {
    50% { opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes flash {
    50% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, there is also a good article on velocity.js and GSAP http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/09/04/animating-without-jquery/

Comment: And velocity.js is recommend by ricosta cruz himself in his gitHub Readme. https://github.com/rstacruz/jquery.transit#alternatives